# Unable to create initial connections of pool. : Could not create connection to database server

Tags: tomcat

I am stuck with below error, Although the connection is successful to localhost but still getting below mentioned error

```
 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
        com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

Do provide some insight about the error and how to fix this issue

Comment: Are the server and client on the same machine? if not, maybe there's firewalling active on the server?